# invalid use of void expression in c printf

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I am studying c.
I have this struc:

```
typedef struct mystuff
{
    char* name;
    int      val;
}MyStuff;
```

In main I call:

```
MyStuff fruit1 ={"watermellon", 1};
```

I pass data to insertLifo:

```
insertLifo(myQueue, &fruit1);
```

This is the function

```
bool insertLifo(LifoQueue queue, void* data)
```

Inside the function I want to print the data in order to debug:

```
printf("insertLifo()  %s \n", *data);
```

I get the following error:

```
MemAlloc.c: In function ‘insertLifo’:
MemAlloc.c:42:32: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [enabled by default]
  printf("insertLifo()  %s \n", *data);
                                ^
MemAlloc.c:42:2: error: invalid use of void expression
  printf("insertLifo()  %s \n", *data);
  ^
```

I have tried:

```
printf("insertLifo()  %p \n", (void*)*data);
```

and other ways.

I want to understand fully how to use pointers

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Comment: the value of data. In this example "watermellon"

Comment: Your `data` has type `void *`, therefore the expression `*data` has type `void`.  There's pretty much nothing you can do with a value of type `void`.  The pointer, however, you can cast to a different pointer type.  It might be meaningful to dereference the result of such a cast.  But if you know what type to cast to, then you ought to declare a pointer of the correct type in the first place, so that no casting is needed.

Comment: Off-topic: LIFO is a stack, not queue

Comment: I tried casting to a char* but it didn't work.

Comment: I was working with an example given me from Stanford Learning to program in c

Comment: No, casting to `char *` *wouldn't* work (as you intend), because the actual argument does not point to the string you want to print.  It points to a `MyStuff` that contains a pointer to the target string as a member.  If you cast, you would cast to `MyStruff *`, and use the result appropriately for its type.

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to make it complete and verifiable... When you say _something fails_... **we want to see _how it fails_**... we cannot believe you, or you'd never asked for help.

Comment: A properly written LIFO ADT wouldn't know a thing about the data it contains. Most certainly it would not know how to print it etc. It's just a dumb container used for storing things. All application logic should be placed outside it.

Answer (score 3):

A `void *` is a generic pointer.  The type of the data it points to is unknown, therefore you can't dereference a `void *`.

You should change your function to accept a `MyStuff  *` and modify the `printf` call to print each field.

```
bool insertLifo(LifoQueue queue, MyStuff* data)
{
    ...
    printf("insertLifo()  name=%s val=%d \n", data->name, data->val);
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is in how you declare `insertLifo()`, as you declare incorrectly the second parameter.  It should be:

```
bool insertLifo(LifoQueue queue, MyStuff* data)
```

so you can pass the variable by reference.  Then, you have to do:

```
printf("bla bla %s", data->name);
```

as the `%s` format specifier requires to pass a parameter of type `char *`, as `name` is.

But, as I told you in a comment to your question, we need a complete and verifiable example to be able to make a diagnostic.  You didn't do this, so you get incomplete responses. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Another mistake is that probably you need to pass also the first parameter of `insertLifo()` by reference, as you'll need probably to modify that structure, and if you pass it by value, it will be copied into the function, and any modification you do to it will be lost at function return.

Finally, you say

> I want to understand fully how to use pointers.

Well, that's completely out of the scope of this application.  StackOverflow is only to help you to correct a small problem in your code, but not to teach you how to program.  I can say that many people pass all they lifes trying to understand how to use pointers and never succeed.  That depends on many aspects, but a good thing you can do is to buy a good book on C.

Answer (score 1):

In order to print pointer address you shell use `%p` [printf format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) instead of `%s` which is for the string.

If you need a to string printf you can use following:

```
MyStuff *stuff = (MyStuff*)data;
printf("insertLifo() data=%p = {name=%s, val=%d} \n", data, stuff->name, stuff->val);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will study both comments attentively in order to fully understand them.

Comment: `%p` expects a `void *` pointer. You should cast `stuff` as `(void *)stuff` for complete portability

Comment: Yes for `C++` i.e. `static_cast<const void*>(stuff)` but not for [C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/void-pointer-c-cpp/). Otherwise, you will alsways cast for functions like memcmp, memcpy, memmove etc.

Comment: @VictorGubin those functions are affected by prototypes which control implicit conversions, whereas printf arguments are not (the comment by chqrline is correct)